# VBA script to search for a string in a column and delete an entire row containing that string?

Tags: excel, vba

I have some 100 rows with some 10 columns.I want to delete the entire row if the cell in column B(or 2) contains a specific string "XYZ" (say)

The below code works perfect if the string is present in the beginning.
But I want it to work for below cases as well:

1. "XYZadjsaoda"      (Case 1: Beginning of the string)
2. "asdsalXYZasdsa"   (Case 2: Middle of the string )
3. "dsadsad32XYZ"     (Case 3: End of the string)

If the string is present it should delete the entire row.

```
Sub DeleteRowBasedOnCriteria()
    Dim RowToTest As Long
    Sheets("Jira").Select
    For RowToTest = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
        With Cells(RowToTest, 2)
            If .Value = "XYZ" _        
            Then _
            Rows(RowToTest).EntireRow.Delete
        End With
    Next RowToTest
End Sub
```

The function should match XYZ irrespective of the location inside a cell and delete entire row.

Comment: I recommend to read [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Like operator with wildcards (possibly with a case qualification too).

AutoFilter might be a better option though.

```
Sub DeleteRowBasedOnCriteria()
Dim RowToTest As Long
Sheets("Jira").Select
For RowToTest = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
    With Cells(RowToTest, 2)
        If .Value Like "*XYZ*" Then Rows(RowToTest).EntireRow.Delete
        'If ucase(.Value) Like "*XYZ*" Then Rows(RowToTest).EntireRow.Delete  CASE INSENSITIVE 
    End With
Next RowToTest
End Sub
```

Comment: had been stuck with this for a week!

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively to the `Like` operator you can use the [InStr function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/instr-function):

```
If InStr(1, "XYZ", .Value, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
```

You can use …

- `vbTextCompare` to make it not case sensitive.
- `vbBinaryCompare` to make it case sensitive.